# Error al iniciar activity GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tengo un error al iniciar mi actividad en donde está googlemaps

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.appmovilperote, PID: 9854 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.appmovilperote/com.appmovilperote.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null
>   object reference      at
>   com.appmovilperote.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:90)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>     ... 9 more

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageView imvruta;

    public static String nombre;
    public static double lat, lng;
    public static LatLng destin;
    public static LatLng orign;
    double  latitude;
    double longitud;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        lat = extras.getDouble("LATITUD");
        lng = extras.getDouble("LONGITUD");
        nombre = extras.getString("NOMBRENEGOCIO");

        destin = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        imvruta = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv_type_ruta);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        //A API 17
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitud = location.getLongitude();

        orign = new LatLng(latitude,longitud);

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                .zoom(17).target(destin).build();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destin).title(nombre)).showInfoWindow();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Me marca error al obtener la longitud y latitud

```
 latitude = location.getLatitude();
 longitud = location.getLongitude();
```

¿Qués estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Lo principal que estas haciendo mal esta tener una excepción y no compartirla entera. La Excepción básicamente te pega con un palo en la cabeza diciéndote donde queda tu error. compártelo, y lo veremos.

Comment: Métete en tu IDE y búsca línea 90 en com.appmovilperote.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity (debe ser en `onCreate(Bundle ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, debe confirmar si el objeto location no es nulo. La excepción ocurre cuando locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false)); devuelve un valor null.

```
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                   if(location != null){ 
                       latitude = location.getLatitude();
                       longitud = location.getLongitude();

                       orign = new LatLng(latitude,longitud);

                     }  else  {
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Última ubicación no reconocida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                     }
```

Comment: Vale gracias amigo ya no se cae la aplicación agregando la línea de código, pero no logro obtener la latitud y longitud me brinca hasta el else como ubicación no reconocida

Comment: Podrías hacer que tu activity implemente LocationListener y en el método  ` @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {latitude = location.getLatitude();
                       longitud = location.getLongitude();}
`

Comment: Gracias amigo :D